# 2S 10C Li-po 6000 mAh step-down to 6 V

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, lipo, high-current

There are a ton of buck converters that can step down 7.4 V to 6 V, but looking at their specs, not all of them can handle the typical Li-po high current discharge rate of say 60 A. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What is your specific application? A buck converter of that specification is typically not a commercial demand that is why most of them are wide voltage range and low current rated.

Comment: Sounds like whatever you're trying to do, you're taking the wrong approach. I know of no application where you would need to step down the entire output of a battery that big.

Comment: @JaySabir It's for a robot we are making. We need to power 12x MG996R servos that require 1-1.5A each. However, they can't take more than 6V inputs or they start jittering and eventually burn off.

Comment: @DKNguyen We need 6V inputs. 1S is 3.7V so we need to step it up to 6V but this means we cut almost half the current. 2S is 7.4V and downgrading this to 6V is a better case scenario. If you have any alternatives, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: @GeorgiDimitrov I looked at your alternatives, you can find 12A adjustable buck converter. Use two of them? https://www.ebay.com/itm/100W-DC-DC-Buck-Step-down-Converter-Module-4-5-30V-to-0-8-30V-12A-Laptop-LED-Car-/262561549684

Comment: @JaySabir Will this be able to withstand the 60A discharge rate current? Isn't 12A the absolute maximum the buck converter can stand?

Comment: Well, the proper way to have done this was to choose 7.4V servos off the start. For example, if you design a robot that has one huge 400W motor, you don't mismatch components so you have to run all that power through an expensive, inefficient, large buck converter. This is true of any high power parts of your robot. That bad design choice notwithstanding, if you need 12x1.5A, why do you need your buck to supply 60A? That's three times more than what you actually said you need.

Comment: @DKNguyen Servo motors usually operate in the 4.5-6V limits. I was thinking of using brush motors as they provide smoother motion but that would require too many robot CAD changes. 
We will eventually add more servos. Maybe 10 more. So that means 22 servos that consume 33A. I've heard it's good practice to add a bit more for the stall. You're correct, we need 40A and not 60A. 
I'm thinking of using a standard LiPo battery of 2S 10C 6000mAh which has a 60A discharge rate. Given the nature of the battery, we can't go lower than this, if we want more juice.

Comment: For 12 servos the max current would be 18A. If you are worried about starting spike then find higher voltage servo like DKNguyen said. Or find a workaround like timing their start at different timeslot if that is an option.

Comment: @GeorgiDimitrov If you're going to add that many more servos DEFINITELY make the switch to 7.4V servos now instead of living with a bad design decision now and then having exacerbating it down the road. Or go with a 18A supply now and add only 7.4V servos later on. It is worth actually wiring up your servos to a bench supply and measuring how much current is actually drawn at any one instant due to the way servos current pulses work. You might not actually be drawing peak current from all servos all at the same time. You say brushed motors as a substitute. Is this robot legged or wheel or what

Comment: Thank you both for the recommendations. I will look more into alternative battery choices.

Comment: Look at lithium iron phosphate. They are in a similar class Lithium POlymers but have slightly lower voltage

Comment: The robot is a quadruped. We are currently using UTP3313TFL which provides 0-30V 0-3A. It was good until we needed the bot to stand up. We used to set it to 5V but later boosted it to 6V to use the servo's more powerful mode. After we added fur, it couldn't stand up anymore. I guess we needed more current, so we ordered the more powerful K3010D capable of 0-10A. We will be testing it today. We are using PCA9685 and that only takes 5A but that's another topic.
I will look into LiFe batteries.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a buck converter good up to 100 A for a work project before.

Try searching for "Buck Converter Design" on Google, and you'll get some awesome tutorials and designs that can help you tailor your own, similar to this:

[Buck Converter Design](https://www.daycounter.com/LabBook/BuckConverter/Buck-Converter-Equations.phtml)

Good hunting!